# How to see what percentage of my users are on which devices?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I would like to know what percentage of my users have access to dual cameras or photo depth information. Or to put it another way, what percentage of my users have one of the following models:

iPhone X
iPhone 6 Plus
iPhone 7 Plus
iPhone 8 Plus

I found the following:

[image]

But can't work out how to dig deeper and get the info I need.

Comment: i think  iPhone 7 Plus, iPhone 8 Plus, and iPhone X only supports depth-of-field effect. Does iPhone 6 Plus support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this.

**Adding a Filter to the Dashboard**

The quick and dirty way is to add a filter to the dashboard, selecting only the models of interest. Compare the user count with the total user count.

**Creating a New Audience**

Create a new audience containing only these models. The new audience only accumulates data after the creation. It will take time before it has enough data, to be meaningful. It has to be edited when new models with dual cameras are released.

**Connecting the Firebase Instance**

Connect the Firebase instance to BigQuery. Query the database for the needed information. This method is flexible and accurate, but would not allow you to query existing data.

Answer (score 0):

good morning, you can't show this information in this section, if you want specific information for your users I recommend use custom events, with this you can customize all necessary and relevant information for you.